# How to convert pixels(Display width of phone) to milliseconds(ms)?

Tags: android, graph, type-conversion, pixel, milliseconds

[image]

I am trying to draw a graph for a recorded sound using the byte array fetched from the file and trying to set it as a background for a seek bar. I had succeeded to draw till the amount shown above, but its not accurate. For getting an accurate graph I need to convert the pixels to milliseconds. Actually the max and progress updates done in the seek bar are in milliseconds.But I am drawing the graph using the pixels of the Display width inside a loop.So I think if I can convert the pixels to milliseconds and draw the graph loping it inside milliseconds could make out an accurate progreesbargraph (Hope so).

So can any one help me to convert the pixels to milliseconds???If the Display width of the phone is 480, I need to convert 480 to milliseconds, Any way??Help me out!!!

```
width=number of pixels of display width
for (int iPixel = 0; iPixel < width; iPixel++)
            { 
                   {
            int start = (int) ((float) iPixel * ((float) width));
            int end = (int) ((float) (iPixel + 1) * ((float) width));

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            //code to find the pixel to draw
            }

   //code to draw in canvas
        }
```

Comment: What's the max length in milliseconds then? I guess length of song. So ratio between max milliseconds and max pixels.

Comment: Do this when recorded or after save recorded file?

Comment: @AwadKab this is been done after saving the file

Comment: @DavidOlsson We have max pixels and milliseconds, how taking ratio solve this? I am drawing inside a loop which loops according to max num of pixels I need to change that loop according to milliseconds.

Comment: @SreedevR how else you do translate from pixels to milliseconds? You need something to transform it by. A ratio between the units.

Comment: I have a loop to draw in canvas which the limit is number of pixels in the display width(Refer to edits in my que).I want to change this loop to  work according to the milliseconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
total width(unit) / total file length(milliseconds) = result(unit/milliseconds)
```

then move your draw by `result` per `milliseconds`

**Edit**:

My suggestion is:

1- Set SeekBar max=100; and min=0;

2- Convert media lenght to percent by use this method:

```
public int getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration, long totalDuration){
        Double percentage = (double) 0;

        long currentSeconds = (int) (currentDuration);
        long totalSeconds = (int) (totalDuration);

        // calculating percentage
        percentage =(((double)currentSeconds)/totalSeconds)*100;

        // return percentage
        return percentage.intValue();
    }
```

then use this persent in SeekBar like `setProgress(getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration, long totalDuration));`

3- Implements `OnSeekBarChangeListener` and use its `progress` parameter to draw your graph:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
    // Here use int progress to draw graph. It is percent
    // Current width = 400*percent/100 = result;
    // draw until result value;
}

/**
 * When user starts moving the progress handler
 * */
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

/**
 * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
 * */
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: This is not working, total width is 480 and total duration is 18947 so the calculation goes like this result=480/18947 and its not looping coz result has not value.No graph is drawing....

Comment: Actually am not drawing the graph at run-time, I have the file saved at SD card. Initially i read the byte, draw the graph using canvas and setting it as background for seekbar. This is the scenario.

Comment: Are you tried to get SeekBar Width `SeekBar.getWidth()`? It is return SeekBar width in pixels.

Comment: yes my seek bar has the same width of the display and am also getting the pixels now i need to convert it to milliseconds to draw.if the total pixels is 480 can it be converted to milliseconds??